# Possibility to open GitHub Actions artifacts via UI

Tags: selenium, github-actions, artifacts

I have added `actions/upload-artifact@v3.0.0` for upload artifacts after Workflow run.
Artifacts are uploaded and I can download them for viewing results.
[image]

But I would like to have possibility to open some files from artifacts directly via browser - without downloading.

Do we have such possibility?